# How do I divide bodycontent in two halves and insert html in the middle using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I've done it with jQuery, but need to do it with PURE JS.

jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bodyContent = Math.floor($('#content').children().length);
  var bodyContentDividedInTwo = Math.floor(bodyContent / 2);


  $('#content').children(':eq('+bodyContentDividedInTwodedInHalf+')').after(`widget goes here`);
});
```

This is where I'm stuck with my PURE JS example:

```
 var fullBodyContent = document.querySelector('#contentBody');
 var bodyContentSplitInHalf = fullBodyContent.childElementCount / 2;

 bodyContentSplitInHalf.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h1>Yeeeeeeesssss!</h1>');
```

Then I get the obvious error of it not being a function. Because its a nodelist.

Please help, I know this is an easy one. But for some reason I always struggle to figure this out.

Comment: `bodyContentSplitInHalf` in your code is not a `NodeList`, it's a `Number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
const index = Math.floor(fullBodyContent.childElementCount / 2);
const bodyContentSplitInHalf = fullBodyContent.children[index];
```

Comment: Hey connexo,
So what I'm trying to do is split body content in two, it then gives me the half of the length of the full body content. Then I'm a bit confused on how to insert my html widget at that middle point of the body.

Comment: You have that line of code already. `bodyContentSplitInHalf.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h1>Yeeeeeeesssss!</h1>');`

Comment: That's the one! Thanx a mil connexo